# How can a function be closed and bounded on the interval [-infinity,infinity]?

Tags: calculus

How can a function be closed and bounded on the interval [-infinity,infinity]? To me the word infinity implies that it would be with out bound. Perhaps I'm getting to caught up in semantics?

Comment: For functions, bounded means $f(x) \leq M$ for some $M \in \Bbb{R}$ and all $x \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Is infinity considered to be a real number? Because if it is than what wouldn't be bounded?

Comment: No, infinity is a bit tricky. It is mostly a concept, not a number. But there are some algebra properties that it obeys and some branches of math deal quite a bit with properties of infinity. For this question, we would not think of infinity as a number.

Comment: So an interval with either infinity or negative infinity will never be bounded then? Or closed either?

Comment: What do you mean the function is closed? There are various notions of closedness, I suspect none apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function is bounded, this means that its codomain, not domain, is bounded. For a function $f(x)$, domain is a set of all $x$-s for which the function is defined, while codomain is a set of all possible values of $f(x)$.

For example, function $\sin x$ takes values from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, but returns only values from $-1$ to $1$, so its domain is $(-\infty,+\infty)=\mathbb R$, while its codomain is only $[-1,1]$, which means that this function is bounded.